# Using SOQL to query Identities using LIKE statement/keyword

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

HI I was wondering If we could use SOQL statements using LIKE on Identities like:

> select Id,Name from Account where  Id not LIKE '001W%' limit 10

So if there were ID strings that start with those 4 characters I can skip those and get 10 that are different.  I tried but I get an exception indicating that I have an 'unexpected token'.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the salesforce documentation:

**The LIKE operator is supported for string fields only.**